# Pull Data-Attribute Value And Hide P Without Matching String

Tags: jquery

**HTML:**

```
<!-- NAV Equivalent -->
<div class="part">
  <a data-type="test">Test</a>
  <a data-type="new">New</a>
</div>

<!-- Items -->    
<div>
  <h5>Example 1</h5>
  <p>Test</p>
</div>

<div>
  <h5>Example 2</h5>
  <p>New</p>
</div>

<!-- Example 3, Test...
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(".part span").click(
  function () {
    var dataType = $(this).attr('data-type');
    $("body").find('p[text*="' + dataType + '"]'):not(:contain("dataType")).addClass("hidden")
  }
);
```

**The way I think/want the jQuery to work:**

When a `span` inside of `.part` is clicked, take the `data-type` of that span, and find a paragraph that contains the same string as that `data-type`'s value, and hide any paragraphs that don't contain that string.

**jsFiddle:**
https://jsfiddle.net/CSS_Apprentice/ft5jLka5/2/

Comment: Not what you're asking, but clickable spans create a bad user experience, because users who can't use a mouse or other pointing device can't use your page. Better to use anchors, which are accessible via keyboard *or* mouse. (Anchors can still be styled as needed.)

Comment: Thanks for the tip! This is actually for a Web Tool for personal use, but noted for future reference; I really appreciate it.

Comment: Went ahead and updated it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got the right idea, but you are trying to call **jQuery** selectors as functions.

Here's a working version.

```js
$(".part span").click(
  function () {
    var dataType = $(this).attr('data-type');
    $('p:not(:contains("' + dataType + '"))').addClass('hidden')

  }
);
```

```css
.hidden{display:none}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="part">
  <span data-type="test">Test</span>
  <span data-type="new">New</span>
</div>

<!-- Items -->    
<div>
  <h5>Example 1</h5>
  <p>Test</p>
</div>

<div>
  <h5>Example 2</h5>
  <p>New</p>
</div>
```

Also, as you mentioned this is a personal dev tool, you can write the string concatenation using javascript ES6 [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals). Much prettier!

```
$(`p:not(:contains("${dataType}"))`).addClass('hidden')
```

Comment: Thank you for the hasty & detailed answer! When I run your code snippet though, it appears to be hiding both paragraphs.

Comment: @CSSApprentice That will be because it is case-sensitive. ie. if you set data-type="Test" it will work.

Comment: @CSSApprentice I think if you want to the test to be case-insensitive, you would be better to loop over the <p> elements in javascript/jQuery, where you have more control over the string comparison.